# How to use non-final variable inside Java8 streams/filters?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In my use case I would like to update the value of a variable and reference the same in next iteration in streams.

But the java compiler is giving me error. Here is my code

```
static String convertList(        
  List<Map.Entry<String, String>> map,         
  String delimiter,            
  long maxLength        
) {          
    long currentLength = 0L;          
    return map.stream()
    .map(e->e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())        
    .filter(p->{                
      long pLength = p.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;        
      currentLength = currentLength + pLength;        
      if (currentLength <= maxLength) {         
        return true;        
      } else {
        return false;        
      }
    })
  .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));        
}
```

I am trying to get the values from the list to a string until the length [till this iteration] <= maxlength

could someone help me fix this? I am getting `Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final` error.

Comment: This is exactly what Streams are not intended for. By the way, statements like `if (currentLength <= maxLength) { return true; } else { return false; }` are nonsense. Just write `return currentLength <= maxLength;` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your variable must be final / effectively final to use it inside lambda. You can still accomplish your goal by using a final 'container object' like an array - specifically for your example, `long[1]` or `AtomicLong` would work well - the reference is final, but you can change out the contents.

Example based on your code:

```
final long[] currentLength = new long[1];          
return map.stream()
    .map(e->e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())        
    .filter(p->{                
        long pLength = p.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;        
        currentLength[0] = currentLength[0] + pLength;        
        if (currentLength[0] + maxLength <= maxLength) {         
            return true;        
        } else {
            return false;        
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
```

Note, you can also simplify your filter as follows:

```
    .filter(p->{                
        long pLength = p.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;        
        currentLength[0] = currentLength[0] + pLength;        
        return (currentLength[0] + maxLength <= maxLength);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked liked a charm. I just noticed I am not counting the delimiter to the total size. Do you have any suggestion? I am fairly new to Java8.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, but your filter condition looks a little fishy - it'll almost always return false (only when `currentLength` is 0 or negative will it be true, and it's never negative).

Comment: Sorry that was a bug. I updated the question. The check is `if (currentLength <= maxLength) {` .

Comment: Collector is joining the delimiter to the final string on each iteration. I would like to count that bytes as well for the total size restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a loop and `break;` once your condition is fulfilled. It is faster because it can bail out early (the stream would traverse the whole list) and does not violate the specification of [Stream.filter](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) which requires that the passed predicate must be *stateless*.

> `Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`
>
> predicate - a non-interfering, stateless predicate to apply to each element to determine if it should be included

Comment: I was looking for the same. Could you give me a sample code for this problem? That would be really helpful.

Comment: No, I think prose should suffice since writing loops is a very basic task in any programming language and covered by many tutorials.

Comment: i actually should downvote you @the8472 for your last comment. Since its a very "basic task" you could have just wrote it down. Now i have to search the soultion somewhere else again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that `Stream` is the right tool when doing stateful operations but anyway here is a solution that works but looks a bit *hacky*.

```
private static String convertList(List<Map.Entry<String, String>> map, String delimiter, long maxLength) {
    AtomicLong currentLength = new AtomicLong();
    return map.stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
            .peek(s -> currentLength.addAndGet(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length))
            .filter(p -> currentLength.get() <= maxLength)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
}
```